# Backing up installed android-sdk

Tags: android, backup, android-sdk-2.3

For some reasons I need to **reinstall** my Windows 7 OS.

I have android-sdk installed at: `C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk` **and the entire directory weighs 2.5 GB**.

What is the **best way to back up** the 2.5 GB and use after I reinstall my OS ? Using backed up `sdk` would save a considerable amount of time.

Please help.

Comment: Just copy entire folder `andorid-sdk`. After reinstall os just paste this folder in any directory. And from sdk manager in eclipse or studio select this sdk folder. Hope everything will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to Zip the sdk and move to another partition like  D: E: F: , Now after you successfully installed your windows, Install Android Studio, Extract the sdk.zip you made previously and select the sdk folder you just extracted. You need internet connection for the first time while you create a project. It will download some jar otherwise you will get gradle error!!

Answer (score 0):

Just copy entire folder `andorid-sdk`. After reinstall os just paste this folder in any directory. And from sdk manager in eclipse or studio select this sdk folder. Hope everything will work fine.